# Do not focus on error fields using jquery validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have placed a blank div with id `#summery` above my form. When an error occurs I run below code,

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    $("#summary").html("Your form contains <a href='#' class='errorCnt'>" + this.numberOfInvalids() + " errors</a>, see details below.");
    this.defaultShowErrors();
}
```

the code works good, but additionally, the page focus moves to first error input field. I don't want this behavior, instead I want my focus to be on `#summary`, and when I click on `.errorCnt` the focus moves to first error field.

Comment: You could just set focus on `#summary` once needed then?!

Comment: Have you [read the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#focusinvalid)?

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the `.focus()` jquery method

```
$( "#summary" ).focus();
```